# How to scroll or jump to position of PageView.builder or PageController in Flutter?

Tags: scroll, flutter, position, flutter-layout, pageviews

**Issue: Unable to scroll to POSITION after loading the Pageviews using PageController ***

> like ViewPager scroll to specific page in Android

```
Widget _buildCarousel(BuildContext context, int selectedIndex) {

    PageController controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 1, keepPage: true);
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          // you may want to use an aspect ratio here for tablet support
          height: 400.0,
          width: 240,
          child: PageView.builder(
            itemCount: assetImageList.length,
            controller: controller,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
              return _buildCarouselItem(context, selectedIndex, itemIndex);
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally found the answer. Just set the ***initialPage:*** ***mSelectedPosition*** attribute like:

```
child: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: mTemplateModelList.length,
        controller: PageController(initialPage: mSelectedPosition, keepPage: true, viewportFraction: 1),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
          return _buildCarouselItem(context, selectedIndex, itemIndex);
        },
      ),
```

OR if you want to scroll the page after the button is clicked then, you can use **jumpTo()** method  using **PageController** which is clearly mentioned below by another user: @android.

Comment: what is `mSelectedPosition`?

Answer (score 6):

Currently there's 2 options to handle your request:

```
PageView.builder(
  controller: _pageController,
  itemCount: _list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _pageController.jumpToPage(index); // for regular jump
        _pageController.animateToPage(_position, curve: Curves.decelerate, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)); // for animated jump. Requires a curve and a duration
      },
      child: Container();
    );
  }
),
```

Comment: _position how we get this value ??

Comment: That will be the variable you want to move from one index to other

Answer (score 3):

You can use **jumpTo()** method to scroll position for **PageView**.
I have create one changePageViewPostion() method in below example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return StateKeeper();
  }
}

class StateKeeper extends State<MyPageView> {

  PageController controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 1, keepPage: true);
  var currentPageValue = 0.0;
  var mItemCount = 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPageValue = controller.page;
      });
    });
  }

  void changePageViewPostion(int whichPage) {
    if(controller != null){
      whichPage = whichPage + 1; // because position will start from 0
      double jumpPosition = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
      double orgPosition = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
      for(int i=0; i<mItemCount; i++){
        controller.jumpTo(jumpPosition);
        if(i==whichPage){
          break;
        }
        jumpPosition = jumpPosition + orgPosition;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PageView position change'),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return Container(
            color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[

                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Page " + (position + 1).toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                  ),
                ),

                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                        elevation: 0.0,
                        child: new Icon(Icons.check),
                        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
                        onPressed: (){
                          changePageViewPostion(5);
                        }
                    ),),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: mItemCount,
      )
    );
  }


}
```

We can get current position with controller as below:

```
controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPageValue = controller.page.toInt();
        print((currentPageValue + 1).toString());
      });
    });
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to scroll to the next page using a button, you can simply use the following method.

```
  //Create a PageController variable
  late PageController _pageController;
  
  //Initialize the variable in the init method.
  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(
        initialPage: _activePage, keepPage: true, viewportFraction: 1);
    super.initState();
  }

  //Use this nextPage() method in the onPressed() method.
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      _activePage < 2
         ? _activePage++
         : Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
             context, LoginScreen.id);
    });

    _pageController.nextPage(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.decelerate,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

remember when going to a particular screen in pageview  don't use

**child: PageView.builder(  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), )**

it disable scrollable